# Can't pass value from one function to another. aiogram | FSM

Tags: python, telegram-bot, fsm, aiogram

Can't pass value from one function to another
i am using aiogram and FSM to pass

```
data['start_name2'] = message.text
```

from one function to another
who can tell me what is my mistake?

This function creates a state in the "Start" state group with the name "start_name2".
class Start(StatesGroup):

```
    start_name2= State() #NAME
```

This is a telegram bot function that handles a callback query with the data 'NAME'. When triggered, the bot will send a message to the chat asking the user to write their name. The input name is then processed and sent to a GET API request, and the received information is then parsed and displayed in a limited form as messages in the chat. If the input name is invalid, the bot will send a message saying so. The function also adds a message with a link to a website at the end.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'NAME')
async def process_callback_button2(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.message.chat.id, text='Please write name. Example : Alex Bortin',reply_markup=kb.inline_kb4)
    await Start.start_name2.set() 
    try:
        await callback_query.message.delete()
    except Exception as exception: 
        print("someone click button")
@dp.message_handler(state=Start.start_name2)
async def namee(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Check if the input is valid
    if not is_valid_input2(message.text):
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Invalid input. Please enter a valid name.")
        return
    name = message.text 
    async with state.proxy() as data:   
        data['start_name2'] = message.text
    try:
        msg = await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, parse_mode="HTML" ,text=f'Entered name: <b>{name}</b>\n\nSearching...')#---
        await bot.send_chat_action(message.from_user.id , ChatActions.TYPING)#---
        for i in range(3):#---
            random_emojis = random.sample(emojis, 4)#---
            random_emojis_string = " ".join(random_emojis)#---
            await asyncio.sleep(0.4)
            await msg.edit_text(parse_mode="HTML" ,text=f'Entered name: <b>{name}</b>')#---
        URL = "API" 
        URL2 = "JUST URL"
        #  GET
        response_text = await fetch(URL)
        soup =  BeautifulSoup(response_text, "html.parser")
        nameD = (soup.prettify())
        print(nameD)
        await msg.edit_text(parse_mode="HTML" ,text=f'Entered name: <b>{name}</b>')  #---
        pattern_value = r'"value"\s*:\s*(\d+),'
        obj = json.loads(nameD)
        data2 = ""
        match_address = re.search(pattern_value, nameD)
        if match_address:
            value = match_address.group(1)
            data2 += f'Data found: <b>{value}</b>\n'
        else:
            data2 += 'Data found: <b>0</b>\n'
        count = 0
        for index in obj['hits']['hits']:
            if count >= 10:
                break
            count += 1
            db_name = index['_index']
            strings = set()
            for a, b in index['_source'].items():
                strings.add(f"<b>{a}</b> : {b}")
            string = "\n".join(list(strings))
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=f"<b>data base name</b> : {db_name}\n{string}", parse_mode="HTML")
        await message.reply('Page 0', reply_markup=get_keyboard(0))
        text2 = hlink('website', URL2)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, parse_mode="HTML" , text=f'\nThe report can be viewed on our WEB {text2}')
        name = 0
    except Exception as exception: 
        name = 0
        text2 = hlink('website', URL2)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, parse_mode="HTML" , text=f'\nThe report can be viewed on our WEB {text2}')
    await state.finish()
```

This function is a callback handler for a callback query in the Telegram Bot API. It handles a vote "up" action, increasing the vote count by 1. It logs the callback data and retrieves a value from the state proxy (stored data). It also prints the retrieved value.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(vote_cb.filter(action='up'))
async def vote_up_cb_handler(query: types.CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict, state: FSMContext):
    logging.info(callback_data)
    amount = int(callback_data['amount'])
    amount += 1
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        start_name2 = data.get('start_name2')
    print(start_name2)
    #Here I try print start_name2
```

The maximum that I have achieved is that my last function outputs

```
"None"
```

Comment: Post a [mre]. Anyway you should specify the ```state``` argument in the second ```@dp.callback_query_handler()``` decorator.